# iOS 8.4 using NSStream with SSL enabled OSError -9850

Tags: ios, ssl, nsstream

I'm trying to connect to a server with a custom protocol with an NSStream, with SSL enabled.  Though I keep getting these errors:

Console:

```
CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9850)
```

Inside the app from [stream streamError]:

```
OSStatus error -9850.
```

To make sure the servers' SSL implementation is not messed up, I also tried to use socat as an intermediary:

```
socat -d -d openssl-listen:1588,fork,cert=server.pem,verify=0 TCP4:localhost:1589
```

I disabled certificate chain checking, in order to make sure the certificate itself is not at fault:
CFDictionaryAddValue(sslDictionary, CFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain, kCFBooleanFalse);

My last straw was setting NSAppTransportSecurity settings, like this:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>my.domain</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.0</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Zero changes in behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The names of the exception keys has been updated from the session. See [App Transport Security Technote](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/) for the new names.

```
NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads
  -> NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads
NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy
  -> NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy
NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion
  -> NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion
```